# Is this a Poisson GLM problem? or OLS? Predicting Counts for a future window of time

Tags: regression, predictive-models, least-squares, poisson-distribution, autoregressive

Say I have one day's worth of a GIANT food court's order data whose per minute order distribution looks like this (1440 mins in the day):

[image]

But the catch is that the food court is comprised of, say, 100 restaurants, and the an individual restaurant's order data can look more like this.

[image]

Much more sparse/noisey.

Working with this one day's worth of data, if - for a future day - given a restaurant and the start-time, I want to predict the total order count for that restaurant for the next 30mins, what's the best way to approach/model this?

I was thinking 3 things:

**1. OLS with an "outside-in" approach.**

I'm able to 'look back' earlier in any given day, so I can compute a rolling-sum window of orders over the past n minutes, and then use that to predict the order count for the current time. Recursively do that 30x, and then I'll have a prediction of the food court's order count for the next 30 minutes. Look at the proportion of orders from that restaurant compared to the food court, and multiply the estimated food court's order count by that proportion.

Could I also maybe approach it by evenly dividing the predicted food court's order count by the # of restaurants, and then doing some form of empirical bayes estimation and padding my estimate with the actual restaurant's order stats from that time?

Drawback to these two methods: They feel super stupid.

**2. Poisson.**

For the food court as a whole, I know the rate of orders/min.

For each restaurant, I can also compute the rate of orders/min.

Can I make Poisson predictions with this?

OR should I be computing lambdas for every min-30min block (i.e. 7:00-7:30 has 5 orders/min, 7:01-7:31 has 4.5 orders/min) and going from there?

For bimodal distributions like this, I've seen COM-Poisson (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution) pop up.. is this what I should be after? Or maybe some other additive model?

Note: Would this be simpler if I wanted to focus just on modeling/predicting the second bump around dinnertime?

**3. Poisson Autoregressive 1**

To be honest, I know nothing about this outside of the fact that it's backwards looking (does this mean it kind of has an exponentially weighted moving average element to it?) - it was just a suggestion and wanted to see if anyone was like 'yes! this is it!'.

Thanks in advance everyone.